# Why would one field in one row return null (when its not) in php / mysql dataset?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a set of data returning and everything looks good except for one row -- Im looking into the database and the field (locationName) on that row has a value ... i have NO IDEA why this one row keeps returning NULL.

**Here is the query :**

```
if( $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT locID, LocationName, Address, Address2, City, State, Zip, PhoneWork, Email FROM tnLocation WHERE locEnabled = 1 ORDER BY LocationName")) {  

        $rows = array();
        //fetch associative array
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }        
        echo json_encode($rows);
        mysqli_free_result($result);         
    }
```

**Here is a shot of the table:**

[image: The table with the field that is returning NULL]

**And here is what is coming back in the object:**

[image: The object with null]

I am completely at a loss here.. everyone of the other rows is just fine.  If I copy and paste my query right into my phpMySQL it comes back with the name ... ?

Comment: Don't post images of your code - post the code itself.

Comment: what is the type of that row. maybe is because of json_encode as the answer said

Comment: Its a varchar... I went in and edited the field and now its returning fine... any clue what invisible critter could have been lurking in that field to cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is `json_encode()` is panicking and converting the field to `null`, possibly due to the data not being encoded in UTF-8. If you `var_dump()` the row, does everything look normal?

Comment: I didnt do a var dump but did delete the field and re-write it and now its back.  This was a conversion from SQL db ..so I guess something got into that field that caused that...thank you!!!  Now to figure out what caused it and prevent it!